# symfony forms customize choicetype widget name

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to customize form theme choice type, in the docs the example is integer_widget. i cannot find the name for choice type, should be something like choice_widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all base widgets under `/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resource/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig` including `choice_widget`.